# Plan d'action ou plan d'actions ?

Tags: usage, pluriel

Je me pose systématiquement la question dès lors que je dois rédiger la description d'une tâche bien précise, ou l'énoncé d'un objectif : doit-on écrire plan d'action (le mot "action" étant au singulier), ou plan d'actions (le mot étant alors au pluriel), sachant bien évidemment qu'on parle de plusieurs actions ?

Et existe-t-il une règle qui explicite cet usage ou non du pluriel dans d'autres cas similaires ?

Answer (score 7):

Comme décrit dans *[la réponse](http://lesdefinitions.fr/plan-d-action)* qui correspond à votre question il s'agit de *l'action singulière* d'un plan, et l'action de cette dernière peut être fractionnée dans le temps et dans des espaces différents.

Sinon on dira moins le *plan des actions* à engager, que le *programme des actions* à engager.

Le plan définit une architecture de l'action, le programme définit la procédure et le déroulement des sous-actions induites.

Tout simplement :

- au singulier : le plan *de* [une] action — contraction en *d'action*
- au pluriel : le plan *de les* actions — contraction en *des actions* (pas de *d'* au pluriel).
- si *action* est une part de capital : le *plan d'actions* n'a pas de sens, on passe aux plans d'investissement pour lesquels on achète ou vend des actions, parfois dans des sociétés différentes.

Comment: _Plan d'achat d'actions_ me semble possible (mais _d'_ n'est pas une contraction de _de les_).

Comment: @Unfrancophone Ne s'agit-il pas *d'achat **de*** qui s'élide devant un mot commençant par une voyelle ?

Comment: Le _d'_ est pour moi plutôt une contraction de _de des_ (avec _des_ l'article partitif ou l'article indéfini pluriel suivant la nomenclature que tu veux utiliser).  C'est pas propre à l'utilisation après _achat_.

Comment: Stéphane à répondu au problème grammatical sur http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17794280#17794280